# groupby_dynamic with selfdesigned index

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

how to make something like   `groupby_dynamic`  but can support a user-defined index

the groupby_dynamic can support timeindex to make a operation as a resample

but can only support the range of a non-duplicate way, such as

```
time
day1   9:00
day1 15:00
day2  9:00
day2  15:00
day3  9:00
day3 15:00
```

dynamic groupby to 1D

```
day1  9:00
day1 15:00
--------------
day2  9:00
day2  15:00
-------------
day3  9:00
day3 15:00
```

the feature i ask is a more user-defined way to dynamic-groupby, and the index may be duplicated

```
day1  9:00
day1 15:00

day2  9:00
day2  15:00
-------------
day2  9:00
day2  15:00
day3  9:00
day3 15:00
--------------
```

i can use rolling in a series, but the rolling_apply waste a lot of time cause it roll every index

```
day1  9:00
day1 15:00

day2  9:00
day2  15:00
-------------
day1 15:00
day2  9:00
day2  15:00
day3  9:00      
--------------  -------> this window is useless
day2  9:00
day2  15:00
day3  9:00
day3  15:00
-------------

day2  15:00
day3  9:00
day3  15:00
day4  9:00   
------------  -------> this window is useless
```

[example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfeCC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to give a different value between the every || period.

- `every` decides the output of the index.
- `periods` gives the window you need.

Examples

```py
import datetime
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
      "time": pl.date_range(
           low=datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 16),
            high=datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 22),
            interval="12h",
         ),
         "n": [1 for i in range(13)]
}
 )

df.groupby_dynamic('time', period='2d', every='1d',include_boundaries=True,truncate=False,closed='right').agg( pl.col('n').sum())
```